# Translating Meta Value to Text in Woocommerce Order Details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

UPDATE: Solved in example below.

I'm trying to have my order details display a payment method based on a custom order field. I can get it to display the numerical values, but I need this to be translated to text.

Here's the code I'm using, but it always displays 'Check' instead of the correct values. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I'm using get_post_meta, but I haven't been able to solve it.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    $method = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_payment', true );
        if ( $method == 1 )
                print '<p><strong>Payment Method:</strong></p> Check';
    
        else if ( $method == 2 )
                print '<p><strong>Payment Method:</strong></p> ACH';
    
        else if ( $method == 3 )
                print '<p><strong>Payment Method:</strong></p> Credit Card';
    
        else if ( $method == 4 )
                print '<p><strong>Payment Method:</strong></p> Master Nursery';
}
```

Comment: change all occurrences of  `if ( $method = ` to `if ( $method == `… It should work now.

Comment: *Facepalm* ...Thank you Loic!

Comment: I have updated the code as shown above and now it's not displaying anything.

Comment: Ok, got it working. Forgot to add True in the get_post_meta arguments.

Comment: You can also replace `$method = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'billing_payment', true );` with `$method = $order->get_meta('billing_payment');`.